# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC only returning first digit of integer

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) to return multiple rows from an SQL query. This function is only returning the first digit of the integer columns. For example, I am expecting "59" and I am getting "5" returned. The query I wrote returns four columns, three of them are integers and one is a string (varchar). The string column is working, but the integer columns are being truncated after the first digit.

This code is nested in a higher level query and I am successfully pulling the variables used in the query.

In order to identify the issue I am echoing back the output and comparing it to what I get when I run the SQL statement in MySQL.

Correct Data:

[image: Correct Data]

Incorrect Data:

[image: Incorrect Data]

```php
$picksQry = $dbcnx->prepare("SELECT gi.gameNo AS gameNo
    , p.pickCD as pickCD
    , t.teamName as teamName
    , p.isLock as isLock

    FROM NCF_gamesInLeague gi JOIN NCF_games g ON gi.gameID = g.gameID
    JOIN ALL_usersInLeague ui ON gi.leagueID = ui.leagueID
    LEFT JOIN NCF_picks p ON gi.gilID = p.gilID AND p.uilID = :uilIDZ
    LEFT JOIN ALL_teams t ON p.pickCD = t.teamCD

    WHERE g.weekID = :week
    AND g.season = :year
    AND ui.userID = :usersID
    AND ui.leagueID = :leagueID

    ORDER BY gameNo ASC");

$picksQry->execute(array(
    ':uilIDZ' => $uilIDZ
, ':week' => $week
, ':year' => $year
, ':usersID' => $userIDZ[$leagueCnt][$userCnt]
, ':leagueID' => $leagueID[$leagueCnt]
));

$picksRow = $picksQry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$picksCnt = 1;

while ($picksRow == true) {
    $gameNo[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['gameNo'];
    $pickCD[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['pickCD'];
    $teamName[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['teamName'];
    $isLock[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['isLock'];
    $picksRow = $picksQry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $picksCnt++;

}
```

The first row of this query should be "1" "59" "Miami FL" "0" but I am getting "5" instead of "59"; and as the loop progresses, any number >10 is only having it's first digit returned.

EDIT: I added the print_r($picksRow) as suggested below and get the array that I expect, however the echoed data is still incorrect. 
 I updated the code to include print_r to see the array. The array is correct, but the data echoed back is still not correct:
Array:  ( [gameNo] => 1 **[pickCD] => 59** [teamName] => Miami FL [isLock] => 0 )
Data: GameNo =1 | **pickCD = 5** | teamName = Miami FL | isLock = 0

The while loop is now:

```php
while ($picksRow = $picksQry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                print_r($picksRow);

                $gameNo[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['gameNo'];
                $pickCD[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['pickCD'];
                $teamName[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['teamName'];
                $isLock[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt] = $picksRow['isLock'];

                echo '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp GameNo ='.$gameNo[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt]
                    .' | pickCD = '.$pickCD[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt]
                    .' | teamName = '.$teamName[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt]
                    .' | isLock = '.$isLock[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt].'<br>';

                $picksCnt++;    

            }
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Show us how you `echo` the results, try to `print_r($picksRow)` and check what is the value that was returned from the query

Comment: Your `while` statement isn't right. I think your current implementation would produce an infinite loop. Should be `while ($picksRow = $picksQry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`. Remove `$picksRow = $picksQry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  ..  Don't use images..

Comment: @waterloomatt `while` statement is __correct__, strange but correct.

Comment: *"Your while statement isn't right. I think your current implementation would produce an infinite loop"* @waterloomatt  no it will not infinite loop..    But i agree doing `while ($picksRow = $picksQry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { }` and removing `$picksRow = $picksQry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` out the loop structure would make more sense..

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($pickCD);`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe found the issue. It appears as if it's related to how I named the variables. I had an earlier variable named "$pickCD[$leagueCnt][$gi]" and, later, the variable "$pickCD[$leagueCnt][$userCnt][$picksCnt]". I renamed the later variable to $pickCDX and it worked correctly. Bambo, waterloomatt and Raymond, thank you for pointing me in the right direction on finding this error.

I am not sure how this affected my output because isn't $pickCD[1][1] is different than $pickCD[1][1][1]?, perhaps someone with a lot more wisdom can explain that. Anyhow, watch how you name your variables, especially in nesting loop statements.

Comment: if `$pickCD[1][1]` is a string datatype, then `$pickCD[1][1][1]` will be the second character in that string. So if `$pickCD[1][1]` === "123"; then `$pickCD[1][1][1]` = `"2"` (because the first is `$pickCD[1][1][0]` ).

Comment: All SQL data in PHP is imported as `string` type.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, Martin. That makes sense.